# Can the icon of a datepicker be changed in ant desing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, antd

I want to change the icon of a date picker from the ant design framework to a material ui icon
is it possible to do that?
[image]

icono of material ui

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup.

You can use `suffixIcon` property.

ex;

```js
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

const deleteIcon = <DeleteIcon />;

...
    <DatePicker onChange={onChange} suffixIcon={deleteIcon} />
...
```